CSS Animation-Iteration-Count messes with Animation-fill-mode
When animation-fill-mode is forwards and using Animation-Iteration-Count to repeat the animation, the animation resets after each iteration until the last, where animation-fill-mode seems to work.
I wanted to animate a div moving forward from 0px to 200px in two movements. When I made the animation, it moved 100px once, reset to 0px, then moved 100px again - it ended up at 100px rather than the intended 200px. I tested it on firefox and edge - neither worked. I wasn't able to find anyone with my problem on google.
I intend to use this animation on multiple elements, but I want some to move forward more times than others. I'd prefer not to use JS.
I apologize for any inaccuracies in my question - this is my first time using stackoverflow.
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: animation 2s 2 forwards;
}

@keyframes animation {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
}

<div></div>


I posted an answer but realize that you may want the animation to go to 100px then reset to 0px and go to 200px ?

I've found a solution using JS. The problem apparently isn't animation-fill-mode forwards, it's the animation resetting the transform each time. If you instead use a script to set the transform differently every iteration, then add transitions, the problem is fixed.


div = document.querySelector("div");
console.log(div);
i = 1;
x = setInterval(() => {
  var transform = "translateX("+i*100+"px)";
  div.style.transform = transform;
  div.style.webkitTransform = transform;
  div.style.msTransform = transform;
  if (i==2) {
    clearInterval(x);
  }
  i++;
  console.log(div.style.transform);
}, 1500);
div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  transition:transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
<div></div>




You can remove the repetiton in animation and change the keyframe :


div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: animation 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes animation {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
}
<div></div>




I wanted to have only one animation to transition from 0 to 100px, as I will be using it for multiple different elements with different iteration counts. Is there any other way that you know of to do this without resetting? Thanks!

I would suggest you to make 2 keyframes.
